# DocumentDb .NET Core SDK - IQueryable.OrderBy generates invalid query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, iqueryable, azure-cosmosdb

The following code is for an **ASP.NET Core** API that uses `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`(version 1.2.1) package and LINQ to construct a query against DocumentDb database.

However, the **generated query is invalid!**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync
  (Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string orderByProperty)
{
   client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(myCollectionUri)
       .Where(predicate)
       .OrderBy(x => orderByProperty)
       .AsDocumentQuery();

   /* rest of the code... */
}

// And I call it:
await repository.QueryAsync<Book>(x => x.Author == "Joe", "Price");

// class Book is a POCO with 3 properties: string Title, string Author, and decimal Price

/*
INVALID generated query:
    SELECT * FROM root WHERE (root["Author"] = "Joe") ORDER BY "Price"

Correct query:
    SELECT * FROM root WHERE (root["Author"] = "Joe") ORDER BY root["Price"]
*/
```

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Maybe by writing an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` and calling it like this:

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(myCollectionUri)
    .Where(predicate)
    .DocumentDbOrderBy(orderByProperty) // new extension method
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: Why does your `OrderBy` still contains `AuthorId`, when you want it to be with the `Price`. Also instead of worrying about the query generated, can you suggest are you getting incorrect results with `Price Asc`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I made up the sample based on my real scenario. Just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using **Dynamic LINQ**.

Added the using statement to my repository class:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
```

And a small change in the method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync
  (Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string orderByProperty)
{
   client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(myCollectionUri)
       .Where(predicate)
       .OrderBy(orderByProperty)   // uses dynamic LINQ
       .AsDocumentQuery();

   /* rest of the code... */
}
```